# Remove only one of socket.io event handlers

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I want to write an application that does the following:

1. Starts a counter starting from 00:00, and increases time by 30 minutes around every passing second
2. Clients can connect to the server and check the time that it currently has
3. Clients can press press a button that increases the time by an additional 30 minutes

I want to build on it further, this is why I'm using Socket.io, but for now I just want to accomplish these three things. I have the following code after server initialization:

```
const io = socketio(server)

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  logger.info(`There is a new connection! ${socket.id}`)

  // Initialize time
  initializeTime(socket)
  
  // Start clock
  startClock(io)

  // Remove all handlers from 'connection'
  io.removeAllListeners('connection', startClock)

  // Increase time if user presses button
  socket.on('increaseTime', increaseTime)
})



function initializeTime(socket) {
  socket.emit('time', `${currentTime.utc().format('HH:mm')}`)
  logger.info(`Clock set up to ${currentTime.utc().format('HH:mm')}`)
}

function startClock(io) {
  setInterval(() => {
    currentTime.add(30, 'minutes')
    io.emit('time', `${currentTime.utc().format('HH:mm')}`)
    logger.info(`Clock updated to ${currentTime.utc().format('HH:mm')}`)
  }, 1250)
}

function increaseTime() {
  currentTime.add(30, 'minutes')
  this.emit('time', `${currentTime.utc().format('HH:mm')}`)
  logger.info('Key pressed on client!')
}
```

With this implementation, only the user that was first connected can manually, additionally increase the time on the server. First, I tried to remove only the starClock function from the 'connection' event, but then I realized that I probably can't do that, I can only remove the handler that was passed as a callback argument. This is why I wrote 'removeAllListeners', to show that I (probably) understand that what I'm trying to do is not the right way, and with this approach I would remove everything else that I specified, and this is why only the first client could increase the time.

Then I tried something else, that works perfectly, but still seems like bad code:

```
io.on('connection', function iNeedThis(socket) {
  logger.info(`There is a new connection! ${socket.id}`)

  // Initialize time
  initializeTime(socket)

  // Increase time if user presses button
  socket.on('increaseTime', increaseTime)
})

io.on('connection', function iDoNotNeedThis(socket) {
  // Start clock
  startClock(io)
  io.removeListener('connection', iDoNotNeedThis)
})
```

What would be the solution to make sure that startClock runs on first connection, but only runs once, while everything else runs on all the connections. I feel like I'm missing something conceptually. Thank you!

Comment: perhaps should consider this: "when a user connects there should be logic to determine if a particular function should be ran" instead of explicitly trying to "remove event handler" and trying to manage that as you see it's kind of hard

Comment: This one works. Maybe not as elegant as I thought it could be, but still better than mine. Thanks